# How can I make the line between the text smaller

Tags: android, eclipse, text, line

How can I make the line between the text smaller?

for example, I code the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#373435"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:textStyle="italic" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Text text text"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:typeface="serif" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Text text text"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:typeface="serif" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I get the result as "A" as in the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAa3l.png .. how can I make it like "B"?

Comment: Can you post the whole XML because it appears exactly as "B" in my Eclipse

Comment: Use negative margin for latter textview like  
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"

Comment: given link doest not show any image

Comment: @Faruk Yazıcı I edited it

Comment: @Ravi Sharma yours worked .. thank you :)

Comment: @Abhishek Chaubey it's there .. I guess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below it is showing what you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#373435"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Text text text"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Text text text"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

if you want more closer to the first Textview then for the second textview you need to add `android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"` .then you can get the view more closer to the first view.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this . I hope it helps you**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#373435"
android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="Text text text"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="Text text text"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout .

Answer (score 0):

Do you have padding the parent `ViewGroup` (`LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` etc.)?

If yes, decrease that padding.

If not, you can give negative margin to the `Views`.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="Text text text"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:typeface="serif"
    layout_marginTop="-8dp" />
```